# Media query not working in smartphone browser apps

Tags: html, css, media-queries, fullpage.js

I'm working on a one-page-project that uses [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) to create scrollable, viewport-filling secions. It's pretty straight-forward, on each slide there is one picture and some text. On devices with bigger viewports, I want the picture to float to the left and the text to appear at it's right side. For smaller viewports, I've added a media query that makes the picture fill the viewport width (`width:96vw`) and removed the float property (`float:none; clear:both;`). When I test this in any browser on my PC by reducing the size of the browser window, it works just fine, if the window's width reaches 800px (the condition in the media query is `(max-width:800px)`), the text jumps below the picture and the picture enlarges to the width of the browser window. The jsfiddle I created works as intended as well: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GinSan/ehco10dh/

**However**, I've uploaded the project to my website and opened it on my android phone, and neither the Firefox nor the Chrome app seem to recognize the media query. It applies the float instead, which looks terrible in portrait orientation ... I've tried adding some more style-rules in the media query, none of which seem to be recognized by the mobile browsers.

I've stared at my media query for like half an hour, but I can't find any mistake. Can you? Or could this be related to the fullpage.js library? Or what else might be the problem? According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), media queries are supported by both android apps.

I would post a link for you to check out the problem yourself, but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to. Am I?

Comment: Are you sure your device has less than 800 pixels width on landscape?

Comment: Not on landscape, but I've also tried adding (orientation : portrait) or raising the max-width in the query to like 1200px, still won't work

Comment: First of all figure out the resolution of your phone and its pixels density.

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini. It's resolution is 540 x 960px and according to [this website](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9190_galaxy_s4_mini-5375.php), it's pixel density is ~256 ppi. I'll borrow some other smartphones today and try it out on those, to see if the problem is specific to my device ..